# How can I make the android to mvoe between the waypoints randomly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since the android should fly or move in the air too I guess I should also use physics too ? Not sure.

I added some spheres as waypoints and I want the android to move between them randomly including random range of movement and rotation speed. For example 1-10 range randomly speed for both movement and rotation.

Now what it does when I'm running the game the NAVI (1) is just moving in rounds none stop on small area not sure why, But it's not moving smooth between the spheres.

The idea is to make the NAVI droid to act like it's out of order.

This is screenshot of the NAVI (1) and it's inspector:

[image: NAVI]

This screenshot is of the Waypoints attached to it Waypoints script:

[image: Waypoints]

This is the Waypoints script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objectToMove;
    public float moveSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 3.0f;
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public int currentWP;

    private void Awake()
    {
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        currentWP = 0;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (waypoints.Length == 0) return;

        var lookPos = waypoints[currentWP].transform.position - objectToMove.position;
        lookPos.y = 0;
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
        objectToMove.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToMove.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        objectToMove.position += objectToMove.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Found how to do it. It's working great now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never changing `currentWP`. That means at every frame, you're rotating toward the same nav point and moving the droid back towards it.

You have to change the currentWP only when the droid reaches it. Use OnTrigger between the target nav point and the droid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this .

```
//for example you've got 5 waypoints
currentWaypoint = Random.Range(1, 5);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Since arrays and thelike are zero indexed and the parameters of `Random.Range(int, int)` are inclusive and exclusive respectively, I'd opt for `Random.Range(0,5)` for 5 waypoints. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html